# python discord bot: multiple on_message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am very new to python and I am trying to make a discord bot that sends messages whenever it finds food-related words.  Here is what I came up with, and it's giving me an indentation error on line 147.  Why is that, and what do I do?

EDIT: I've copy-pasted the code from repl.it to here

```
### Alert bot to food words and reply with a message from a list ###
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'spag' in message.content:
        await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(spaghet))
  if 'meat' in message.content:
    await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(meat))
  if 'dinner' in message.content:
    await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(dinner_words))
  if 'lunch' in message.content:
    await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(lunch_words))
  if 'breakfast' in message.content:
    await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(breakfast_words))
  if any (word in message.content for word in omit):
    return
  await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Thank you for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQiwP.png)

Comment: You're probably mixing tabs and spaces. What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: @MattDMo "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level."  I didn't use any spaces, though.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy your code into it, using the code formatting tool (`{}`) to format it properly. Please don't change any of the content, just copy and paste it.

Comment: oh, copy-pasting it into here made my mistake visible to me.  I see what I did and I've fixed it.  Thank you @MattDMo

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if 'spag' in message.content:
      await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(spaghet))
  if 'meat' in message.content:
      await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(meat))
  if 'dinner' in message.content:
      await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(dinner_words))
  if 'lunch' in message.content:
      await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(lunch_words))
  if 'breakfast' in message.content:
      await ctx.channel.send(random.choice(breakfast_words))
  if any (word in message.content for word in omit):
      return
  await bot.process_commands(message)
```

I hope this fixed it, If it didn't try selecting the code and do `shift+tab` to reset the indent and select the code again and press `tab` to reassign the indent